AssertJ's assertThatCode behaves differently than JUnit's assertThrows
I am having this test, junit assestion works well, while the same assertj assertion does not.
@Test
void registerWithDuplicatedEmail() throws EmailAlreadyRegistered {

    Mockito.when(customerCommand.createCustomer("Duplicated", "duplicated@mail.com", "pass"))
            .thenThrow(new EmailAlreadyRegistered());

   assertThrows(EmailAlreadyRegistered.class, () -> registerCustomerUseCase.execute("Duplicated", "duplicated@mail.com", "pass"));
   // (1) this works well

   assertThatCode(() -> registerCustomerUseCase.execute("Duplicated", "duplicated@mail.com", "pass")).hasCause(new EmailAlreadyRegistered());
   // (2) This fails with the error:
   // Expecting a cause with type: "...exception.EmailAlreadyRegistered" and message: null
   // but actualCause had no cause.

   assertThatCode(() -> registerCustomerUseCase.execute("Duplicated", "duplicated@mail.com", "pass")).doesNotThrowAnyException();
   // (3) Although it contradicts the previous one, this also fails with this error:
   // Expecting code not to raise a throwable but caught "...exception.EmailAlreadyRegistered"

   assertThatExceptionOfType(EmailAlreadyRegistered.class).isThrownBy(() -> registerCustomerUseCase.execute("Duplicated", "duplicated@mail.com", "pass"));
   // (4) This also works well

}

RegisterCustomerUseCase is pretty simple:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegisterCustomerUseCase {

    private final CustomerCommand customerCommand;

    public Customer execute(String name, String email, String password) throws EmailAlreadyRegistered {
        return customerCommand.createCustomer(name, email, password);
    }
}

Do you have any idea why cases (2) and (3) fail?

hasCause? odd name to mention the result

.hasCause checks the cause (.getCause()) of an exception, whereas assertThrows checks the exception directly. Your exception does not have a cause and thus the test fails correctly.
You are looking for isInstanceOf with the class (not an instance) as parameter:
assertThatCode(() -> registerCustomerUseCase.execute("Duplicated", "duplicated@mail.com", "pass"))
    .isInstanceOf(EmailAlreadyRegistered.class);

Alternatively, assert with assertThatThrownBy:
assertThatThrownBy(() -> registerCustomerUseCase.execute("Duplicated", "duplicated@mail.com", "pass"))
    .isInstanceOf(EmailAlreadyRegistered.class);


And another alternative, more BDD style with catchThrowable and catchThrowableOfType, cf: https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-exception-assertions-bdd-style
